# Replace but leave between characters unchanged

Tags: notepad++, regex

I need to replace but leave between characters unchanged:

Example:

```
<column name="propertys_uid">30</column>
<column name="property_name">Villa</column>
<column name="property_street">5th street</column>
<column name="property_town">New York</column>
```

should become

```
<yourreference>30</yourreference>
<name>Villa</name>
<street>5th street</street>
<town>New York</town>
```

As you can see the content between > ... < should not be changed. A normal find and replace will not work as the 
 always needs to be different.

Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Looks pretty easy if you use a sed script.

Comment: Thanks for the answers but not sure what a sed script is and how to use it in notepad++ . I think I got the first step to find using <column name="propertys_uid">.*?</column> but its not working at the replace with <yourreference>*?</yourreference>

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this using Notepad++ (as your tag suggests but your question does not explicitly specify) by using Regular Expression mode within the Replace function. For example:

- Find what: `<column name="propertys_uid">(.*)</column>`
- Replace with: `<yourreference>\1</yourreference>`
- Search Mode: Regular Expression

Notepad++'s regular expressions are mostly PCRE-compatible, so you can read up on PCREs to better understand the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Regular Expression Replace to change the `property_` lines

- Find What: `<column name="property_([^"]+)">([^<]+)</[^>]+>`
- Replace With: `<$1>$2</$1>`
- Search Mode: Regular Expression